# embed HTML tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to embed an html tag in Javascript, between the script> tag

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm need this to speed up a page load in asp.net
I'm loading a script in asp.net before the page loads completely. When the page finally loads, I need to have access to the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X) what you're looking for? It allows you to embed XML/XHTML within your JavaScript, like this:

```
var someXml = <div><b>Some Text</b></div>;
```

I doubt that's what you need, but that's the only way you can do what you're asking. <s>Also, I don't think it works in Internet Explorer.</s> Scratch that, it *only* works in Firefox.

If that's not what you want, use `document.write()`, as suggested by others.

---

**Edit:** E4X is now deprecated and has been removed from newer versions of Firefox. Don't use it. You should use jQuery, as the answer below me suggests, or simply create the elements via `document.createElement` and friends and inject them into the document.

Answer (score 4):

Hey maybe you're looking for jQuery.

```
$("p").text("<b>Some</b> new text.");
```

See embedded  HTML tag.

Write Less, Do More

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you want the Javascript to write HTML, you'll have to use `document.write()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you write this inside your body tag then also you can access this using your javascript.

If yo want to check whether the document is ready or not then you can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  tags can contain just text (usually javascript).

Answer (score 0):

document.write('

colour1: ' + colour1 + '
colour2: ' + colour2 + '

');

Answer (score 0):

Using document.write(), though it is generally advised against the use of this method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.write(`
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>html in script tag</p>
            <\/body>
        <\/html>
        `)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```